# uwsgi - remove "address space usage" message from the log file

Tags: python, uwsgi

I'm using uwsgi version 2.0.8 and it's configured as following:

```
/home/user/env/bin/uwsgi
    --chdir=/home/user/code
    --module=XXXXXXX.wsgi:application
    --master
    --pidfile=/tmp/XXXX.pid
    --socket=/tmp/uwsgi.sock
    --chmod-socket
    --processes=9
    --harakiri=2000
    --max-requests=50000
    --vacuum
    --home=/home/user/env
    --stats /tmp/stats.socket
    --stats-minified
    --harakiri-verbose
    --listen=2048
    --log-date
    --log-zero
    --log-slow 2000
    --log-5xx
    --log-4xx
    --gevent 5
    -m
    -b 25000
    -L
    --wsgi-file /home/user/code/wsgi.py
    --touch-chain-reload /home/user/uwsgi.reload
```

And I'm getting a lot of messages like:

```
{address space usage: 1444040704 bytes/1377MB} {rss usage: 759623680 bytes/724MB} [pid: 4655|app: 0|req: 2897724/26075292] 184.172.192.42 () {44 vars in 563 bytes} [Tue Jul  7 18:45:17 2015] POST /some/url/ => generated 0 bytes in 34 msecs (HTTP/1.1 204) 1 headers in 38 bytes (3 switches on core 4)
```

What is the purpose of these messages and how can I remove them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You told uWSGI to log any response with zero size (--log-zero). Instead if you mean removing the memory report just drop the -m flag (it is a shortcut for --memory-report)